# How can I get Rectangle UITableViewCells in an iOS grouped UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a UITableView with style: "Grouped"

By default, the iOS gives me rounded cells, with a white background and a grey separator.

How can I configure the table so that, for only one section of cells, the cells are rectangular (no border radius) and have no separator? - I wish to use a custom background image on these cells.

Thanks in advance -

bo

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try your suggestion yet - I'll let you know if it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make them squared off by creating a dummy cell for the first and last cell and setting the row height to 0 for those cells in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

You can set the seperator to None and clearColor in the inspector section of the storyboard in order to get rid of the seperators.

Then you can just create a custom background image using `backgroundView` for the cell in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
UIImageView *customImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"];
[theCell setBackgroundView:customImage];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two kinds of `UITableViewCell` in the table, original for the standard cells and customized subclass with overridden `drawRect` to draw the other cells depending on `indexPath`.